# Even Ordered Graph Without a Two Set Partition of Induced Subgroups with Odd Ordered Vertices

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose G = (V,E) is a connected graph of positive even order that can't be partitioned into two induced subgraphs G[S] and G[V-S] where each vertex in G[S] and G[V-S] has odd order. What is the order of G?

Comment: @bof I believe they meant to say the degree of a vertex

Comment: @dfish Thanks. And what did they mean to say what they said the graph has "positive even order"?

Comment: @bof I think saying positive might be superfluous, and that instead it can just be said that G is a connected graph of even order.